# How to get a probability value for a binary data observation every minute of the day

Tags: time-series, python, binary-data

I am observing the electrical power availability on the main line at my home as either existing (0) or not existing (1) every minute of the day (we get a lot of power outages in this part of the world). Every day at specified hours the power will be out and I may get a lot of 1's depicting no power availability.

How can I make an algorithm in python to give a probability of having a outage at any given future minute of the day? I have looked at time series analysis but they usually talk about multiple variables and observe a variable which is not binary (for example temperature etc.). Apart from the time of the day, the outage schedule also has a trend of following a specific pattern for any given day of week. For example on every Sunday, the outage may occur from 1PM-2PM and 7PM-8PM but on Monday it might follow different pattern.

I would really appreciate if you could point me in the right direction as to what kind of problem is this and what algorithm might suite prediction. I have rudimentary python machine learning skills. Thanks

Comment: You could see how far you get just by bucketing by hour for a couple weeks, and then computing probabilities by averaging the buckets.  Basically a trivial model-free approach.  Or, in theory you could take any time series approach for real-valued outputs like temperature and then apply a transform like the logistic transform to map it to [0, 1].  But I don't know of any theory or software for fitting these.  Ultimately it will depend on what you think the data-generating process looks like.  Is each day similar but with a small difference? or is each hour of the week quite different, etc.

Comment: Each day might be different. The starting and ending minute of outage might not be very precise. I could do with average over weekdays but it might be very basic and may need a lot of data points before it becomes meaningful. Going forward I plan to include other variables such as temperature and rainfall etc to may be associate lower power outage with improved weather during hot days. Would a simple linear regression work in this case?

Comment: Linear regression won't work because there's nothing constraining the output to [0, 1].  What are you hoping to predict? whether the power will be on one hour from now?  Whether it will be on at 2PM next tuesday?

Comment: So let's say whenever I am recording the value of power availability, I'll check the probability of outage on the next 60 minutes and if let's say the probability sum goes higher than a threshold, it may trigger water tank pump to start. So I am just trying to pre-emptively see the power outage probability. 60 minutes is just an example, it may as well be just next 5 minutes. May be at 1:45 PM the probability of outage on 46, 47, 48, 49 and 50 may look like 0.02, 0.03, 0.75, 0.89 and 0.90 which might indicate higher probability of outage and help me start certain tasks in anticipation or alert